# Differentiation of Indicator Function f ( x ) = 2 x / θ^2 ;0 < x < θ = 0 otherwise?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is said that Indicator Function can't be differentiated. I could not get the logic behind it. Even if we define $0<x<\theta$ such function can't be differentiated.

Well the question is A random sample of size n is taken from distribution with pdf
f ( x ) = 2 x / θ^2 ;0 < x < θ
= 0 otherwise

Now professor is saying that the equation is not differentiable. So can somebody help here with logic that why it is not differentiable.

Comment: A differentiable function should be continuous. A continuous function attaining both $0$ and $1$ should should attain all other intermediate values, while the indicator function does not.

Comment: Does this have something to do with maximum likelihood estimation?

Comment: Note that $\chi_{\varnothing}$ and $\chi_{\mathbb R}$ are in fact differentiable. Also, it is possible that differentiation fails only at a finite number of points, as is the case with $\chi_{\{0\}}$. Even $\chi_{\mathbb Z}$ is differentiable everywhere except at each integer.

Comment: The function you have defined is not an indicator function. It is not differentiable at $\theta$ because $\frac {f(x)-f(\theta)} {(x-\theta)}$ tends to $-\infty$ as x increases to $\theta$.